# Fetch request must have an entity using @FetchRequest in SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui

I am trying to use @FetchRequest to fetch all records from the SQLite database through CoreData. I have setup CoreData stack as shown below:

```
class CoreDataManager {
    
    private let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    private init() {
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "FooModel")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Unable to initialize Core Data \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
}


@main
struct FooAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, CoreDataManager.shared.context)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to access it is my ContentView as shown below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: MyList.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var myLists: FetchedResults<MyList>
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
A fetch request must have an entity.'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Am I missing something?

UPDATE: I removed the MyList.entity() part from the FetchRequest and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
entity: MyList.entity(),
```

From the FetchRequest

Comment: Yes. that works but why did it work when I was providing the correct entity.

Comment: @MaryDoe I think it is a bug, I’ve been getting it lately, I haven’t dug into why but I am assuming that there was an API update. Something changed on Apple’s end recently.