# CoreData - load local and AppGroup NSPersistentContainers

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, ios-app-group, nspersistentcontainer

I want to load both the **local**'s `NSPersistentContainer` **and** the **AppGroup**'s `NSPersistentContainer`

Here is what I did :

```
class MyAppGroupPersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer{
    override class func defaultDirectoryURL() -> URL{
        return FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.myDomain.myApp")!
    }   
}
```

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()
    
    let containerLocal: NSPersistentContainer
    let containerAppGroup: NSPersistentContainer

    init() {
        let a = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp")
        a.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {(x, y) in})

        let b = MyAppGroupPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp")
        b.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {(x, y) in})

        self.containerLocal = a
        self.containerAppGroup = b
}
```

But then, if I execute this code when I click on a SwiftUI button :

```
let allA = try! PersistenceController.shared.containerLocal.viewContext.fetch(GameData.fetchRequest())
let allB = try! PersistenceController.shared.containerAppGroup.viewContext.fetch(GameData.fetchRequest())
print(allA.count)
print(allB.count)
```

It crashes with `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'executeFetchRequest:error: A fetch request must have an entity.'`

But if I remove all the code related to `containerAppGroup` OR `containerLocal` the error disappears and everything is ok. But in this case I cannot access to both containers data while my app is running.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/linking_data_between_two_core_data_stores

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71042928/fetch-request-must-have-an-entity-using-fetchrequest-in-swiftui/71042948#71042948

Comment: I don't get how to code this, I only have one single Default configuration in ```MyApp.xcdatamodeld```. And how to retrieve data from of both "containers" separately?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that calling `loadPersistentStores` twice like that is wrong. What you should do is create two persistent store descriptions, add both to the `persistentStoreDescriptions` property, and then call `loadPersistentStores` once.

Comment: I’m pretty sure too. I’ve looked in the doc and can’t find it written that is why I suggested that first link but the second link is a recent issue and what I think is a bug. I haven’t been able to test it but if two containers do work and the OP uses a manually created fetch request instead of the built in one it might be solved too.

Comment: @TomHarrington Please show me how!

Comment: Persistent store descriptions are well documented. Take a look and come back if you have more specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the 2 stores into 1 container. This is because we can only have one viewContext. There are methods available to choose what stores are used when querying or saving, see [affectedStores](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506518-affectedstores). You can also use configurations in the model editor to choose what entities are in each store.

Comment: Do you have any doc/tutorial on how to load the 2 stores into 1 container?

Comment: https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc19/202/